# On Equivalent Norms in an Infinite Dimensional Vector Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

How many non-equivalent norms can we define in an infinite dimensional vector space? Is there any explicit expression?

Answer (score 9):

There are plenty of non-equivalent norms. Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed space with norm $\|\cdot\|_X$.

Let $Y$ be another normed space with norm $\|\cdot\|_Y$. Let $T\in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ be compact and injective. Then 
$$
\|x\|_T:=\|Tx\|_Y
$$
is a norm on $X$. Moreover, $\|x\|_T \le \|T\|_{\mathcal L(X,Y)} \|x\|_X$. However, both norms cannot be equivalent: If there would be a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
\|x\|_X \le c\|x\|_T = c\|Tx\|_Y \quad\forall x\in X,
$$
this would imply that $T^{-1}$ is a continuous operator from $Im(T)$ to $X$, which is a contradiction (as compact operators cannot have continuous inverses).

Comment: You say, that there is no constant $c$ such that $c\|x\|_X \ge \|x\|_T$. But you have already proved, that $\| T \|$ is such a constant. It should be $c\|x\|_X \leq \|x\|_T$. Then the inverse of $T$ is bounded, which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for spotting! I corrected the argument.

Answer (score 7):

There are exactly $2^{\dim X}$ inequivalent norms on an infinite dimensional vector space. You can find the proof [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.4169/000298910x515811.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

When you are given just a vector space $X$, then you have as many non-equivalent norms on $X$ as many non-isomorphic normed spaces you can find with the same linear dimension. This is the standard `structure transport' argument. For instance, suppose that you are given a vector space of dimension continuum. Then for each infinite-dimensional Banach space $Y$ of linear dimensional dimension $\mathfrak{c}$ you can find a linear bijection $T_Y\colon X\to Y$ which gives you a norm $\|x\|:=\|T_Yx\|$.